# EFCore- Save Entity with child entity records

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, unit-of-work, ef-core-2.0

Here are my models:

```
    public partial class UserDTO
    {
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Userskills> Userskills { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class SkillsmasterDTO
    {
        public sbyte SkillId { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Userskills> Userskills { get; set; }
   }


  public partial class UserskillsDTO
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public sbyte SkillId { get; set; }

        public SkillsmasterDTO Skill { get; set; }
        public UsermasterDTO User { get; set; }
    }

 public class UserMaster
    {
     public int UserId { get; set; }
     public List<UserSkills> UserSkills{get;set;}
    //other fields
    }

 public class SkillsMaster
 {
        public sbyte SkillId { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
 }

    public class UserSkills
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public sbyte SkillId { get; set; }
        public string Skill { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to save UserMaster, and along with that I want to save UserSkills also.
I am sending data in following format:

```
{"FirstName": "Priya",
"LastName": "Dave",
"Email":"priya.dave@xyz.com",
"Password":"123456",
"ContactNo":"1234",
"RoleId":1,
"CreatedBy":15,
"UserTypeId":2,
"LocationId":1,
"BandId":1,
"PostId":1,
"IsActive":1,
"UserSkills":[{"SkillId":1}]
}
```

Code I've written for save is:

```
 var insertedEmployee= unitOfWork.UserRepository.Add(Mapper.Map<Usermaster>(employee));

_unitOfWork.Save();
```

It is saving user details but UserSkills is not getting saved. How can I do that? I went through some blogs but not able to find proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because `UserSkills` is persisted in a different table than `UserMaster`, you need to do the following for a unit of work.

1. Add `UserMaster` to `context.UserMasters` table
2. Add `UserSkills` to `context.UserSkills` table
3. Add `UserSkills` to `context.UserMaster` object
4. Then `context.SaveChanges()`